# nginx : unknown directive "location"

Tags: nginx

Here is my code (starting with line 35):

```
location /

{

  index index.php;
  root  /home/body;

  if ($request_filename !~ (js|css|images|robots\.txt|index\.php.*) ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
[emerg]: unknown directive "location" in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:35
```

Can anyone help how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show me output of <pre>nginx -V</pre> I suppose, that you nginx was builded with <pre>--without-http</pre> option.

Answer (score 13):

Ensure that **location** directive located inside of server block:

```
http {
...
    server {
        ...
        location ...
    }
}
```