# Setup SlimPHP .htaccess in Nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to setup my PHP application in my Raspberry Pi. I'm using a Nginx server to host the application. The SlimPHP requires a .htaccess configuration to redirect all the requests to the index.php file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I've converted the htaccess using the [Winginx tool](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) and edited the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file adding the following source, but Nginx reported a configuration error:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location" in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:98 nginx: configuration file
>
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

How should I proceed?

**UPDATE**

I 've edited the nginx.conf file as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282146/nginx-unknown-directive-location) but the Nginx still doesn't redirecting the URL. It shows a `File not found` answer. Should I edit the *nginx.conf* file or create any other configuration file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx : unknown directive "location"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282146/nginx-unknown-directive-location)

Comment: @Chris Is editing the nginx.conf the correct way?

Comment: Yes, the linked post explains your problem (unless there's some surrounding context to your configuration you haven't posted).

Comment: Actually the correct way is making a new configuration file in `nginx/sites-available` and making a symlink to it in `nginx/sites-enabled`. Also If is Evil. Use `try_files`.

Comment: Could you add an answer with this description, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want something like this. You can toggle the SLIM_MODE to development as needed.

[Edit: Oops, posted an old version, updated to remove the if.]

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; # not needed if you have cgi.fix_pathinfo=false in php.ini
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SLIM_MODE production;
}
```

Comment: Where should I include this config? Which file?

Comment: This goes in your nginx.conf or whatever sub-file it's including for the vhost. I.e., inside the `server` block for your site.

Comment: Its is redirecting to the index.html file, hosted on the root. I have two files, `index.html` and `index.php`. The PHP file contains the Slim PHP logic. The HTML file just make the captive portal feature works. It contains a meta redirect to the PHP file. I need a redirect to the PHP file.

Comment: It seens we're very close! I need to redirect to the `index.php` file, not the `index.html`.

Comment: Just get rid of the index.html file.