# unknown directive "location /" (inside server block)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm getting the following error from a seemingly valid nginx configuration:

`nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location /" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:49`

Here's the relevant part of my `default.conf`:

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    # ssl_password_file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/global.pass;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/docker/code/static;
    }

    location / {  # this is line 49
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
    }
}
```

My problem is different from [nginx : unknown directive "location"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282146/nginx-unknown-directive-location) because the directive is located inside a `server` block.

Note that "mydomain.com" has been replaced with my actual domain, and that almost identical configurations have worked many times before. The main differences between this configuration and previous configurations are that the `ssl_certificate*` settings point to a different location, and there's no `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` because I haven't used certbot/let's encrypt in nginx/docker before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nginx thinks that `location /` is a directive. Check that the space separating the `location` and the `/` is a space character and not missing or some other character code that just appears invisible.

Comment: That's it (some non-space whitespace character by the looks of it). Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error message:

> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location /" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:49

Nginx is reading the quoted text as a single directive, so it has not recognise the gap between the `location` and `/` parts.

The gap should be a white-space character (e.g. ASCII space 20h). It's very probably that you are missing a space separator or your editor has inserted an invisible formatting character that is not a normal ASCII space.